# Using a function from inside a module

Tags: scoping

I try to plot a function for special values of some parameters which I don't want to set globally:

```
a[t_] = Cos[ω0*t + α]*Sinc[Δω*t]

Module[ {
   ω0 = 1, 
   Δω = 0.3, 
   α = Pi/4
}, 
 Plot[a[t], {t, -25, 25}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(0\)]\)t", "a(t)"}
 ]
]
```

This only gives me an empty diagram. If I however replace a[t] by its definition from above it works just fine.
In this case replacing the name of the function by the definition may not be a problem, but I also want to do this with functions where the definitions are very long, so I'd really like to use their names instead. What do I do wrong here?

If this is not possible with module, I'd also be glad about ways to do this with other constructs!

Comment: Why not put the definition for `a` within `Module[]`, then? (Or define `a` to be a multiparameter function.)

Comment: This is exactly what `Module` should do, and what you need is `Block`.

Answer (score 5):

#### Edit

Given that `a` is defined at top-level with free variables

```
a[t_] := Cos[ω0*t + α]*Sinc[Δω*t]
```

the behavior of `a[t]` in `Plot` or anywhere else is a matter of which scope the free variables of `a` are evaluated in.

```
Module[{ω0 = 1, Δω = 0.3, α = Pi/4}, a[1]]
```

gives

```
Cos[α + ω0] Sinc[Δω]
```

because the local variables specified in `Module`'s 1st argument are renamed internally to avoid conflict with the names used for the free variables. `Module` is a lexical scoping construct so that is kind of behavior one should expect. However, you can override this; you can get the free variables renamed by writing

```
 Module[{ω0 = 1, Δω = 0.3, α = Pi/4}, Evaluate[a[1]]]
```

> `-0.209778`

because this is equivalent to writing

```
Module[{ω0 = 1, Δω = 0.3, α = Pi/4}, Cos[ω0*1 + α]*Sinc[Δω*1]]
```

`Block` as Kuba has pointed it out is better designed for this sort of work because it is a dynamic scoping construct; it rebinds the free variables to local values for, and only for, the dynamic extent of the evaluation of the block.

Thus,

```
Block[{ω0 = 1, Δω = 0.3, α = Pi/4}, a[1]]
```

> `-0.209778`

So, if you want to stay with `Module`, write

```
Plot[Module[{ω0 = 1, Δω = 0.3, α = Pi/4}, Evaluate[a[t]]], {t, -25, 25}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(0\)]\)t", "a(t)"}]
```

However, `Block` will give simpler code.

```
Plot[Block[{ω0 = 1, Δω = 0.3, α = Pi/4}, a[t]], {t, -25, 25}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(0\)]\)t", "a(t)"}]

Block[{ω0 = 1, Δω = 0.3, α = Pi/4},
  Plot[a[t], {t, -25, 25}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(0\)]\)t", "a(t)"}]]
```

Note that `Block` is less fussy about its placement because it scopes dynamically rather than lexically.

You could also write

```
Plot[a[t] /. {ω0 -> 1, Δω -> 0.3, α -> Pi/4}, {t, -25, 25}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(0\)]\)t", "a(t)"}]
```

which makes an end-run around the scoping issues because it replaces the free variables with values without introducing any new scoping.

All of these plot expressions produce

[image: plot]

Comment: @Kuba. I have reconsidered and expanded my answer. I hope I have got the scoping issues right and explained them clearly in the edit I have made.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to create a second definition for `a` that is:

```
a[t_, ω0_, Δω_, α_] := Cos[ω0*t + α]*Sinc[Δω*t]
```

Then replace `a[t]` with `a[t, ω0, Δω, α]` in your `Module`

```
Module[
 {
  ω0 = 1,
  Δω = 0.3,
  α = Pi/4
  },
 Plot[a[t, ω0, Δω, α], {t, -25, 25},
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ω\), \(0\)]\)t", "a(t)"}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you need define function `a[t_]` with one variable t ahead.

```
a[t_]:=Module[{ω0 = 1, Δω = 0.3,    α = Pi/4},
    Cos[ω0*t + α]*Sinc[Δω*t] (* return value *)
]
```

ps: Sinc unit is radians.

```
Plot[a[t], {t, -25, 25}, AxesLabel ->           
{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ω\),     \(0\)]\)t", "a(t)"}]
```

[image]